# Javascript function to notify page when to update page?

Tags: javascript, upload

I have an upload function on a page that uploads any attached file.

Below the attachment button, i have a list of uploaded files that fails to refresh and display the latest attached file.

When a small file is added, by the time my refresh function kicks in, it has already uploaded, and so my page refreshes and displays the upload.

problem is, whn i upload a larger file, the refresh kicks in BEFORE the file is uploaded, so no new file is displayed.

Is there a way to wait for the upload and then update the list?

Comment: without seeing you code it's hard to tell how to make it better...

Comment: What are you using for uploading files? Standard HTTP upload would refresh the entire page once the file is completely uploaded. Also, how is your list generated? Could it be that it's read from the database before the file data has been inserted there?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you will post the form with the file to the server, and the server will respond with the updated page when the upload is complete.

If you use a different way of uploading files, you have to use whatever method that solution provides for signalling when the upload is complete. Unless you are using a component (ActiveX/Java/Silverlgith) to do the upload, there is still a form somewhere that is posted to the server, and the server still returns a response when the upload is done.